# Perl : Getting last Friday of the month

Tags: perl, date

I am trying to get the last Friday of the month. I found out the awesome awk script that could to do this job. I try to port it perl but facing some issues. Any insight would be a great help. I can't use any perl modules apart from the inbuilt one, thats why I have to go through building this stuff.

Thanks for your help.

AWK script :

```
BEGIN {
split("31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31",daynum_array,",") # days per month in non leap year
year = ARGV[1]
if (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)) {
  daynum_array[2] = 29
}
y = year - 1
k = 44 + y + int(y/4) + int(6*(y/100)) + int(y/400)
for (m=1; m<=12; m++) {
  k += daynum_array[m]
  d = daynum_array[m] - (k%7)
  printf("%04d-%02d-%02d\n",year,m,d)
}
exit(0)
}
```

My Perl script :

```
my @time            = localtime;
my ($month, $year)  = @time[4, 5];
$year              += 1900;
@months             = qw( 31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 );
$months[1]          = check_leap_year($year) ? 29 : 28;
$y  = $year - 1;
$k  = 44 + $y + int($y / 4) + int(6 * ($y / 100)) + int($y / 400);
$k += $months[$month];
$d  = $months[$month] - ($k % 7);
$month += 1;
printf "%04d-%02d-%02d\n", $year, $month, $d;

sub check_leap_year {
    my $year = shift;
    return 0 if $year % 4;
    return 1 if $year % 100;
    return 0 if $year % 400;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: If you ever find yourself writing your own leap year function, **STOP** and go find a date library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are constrained by using core modules only, this is the way to compute it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Local qw[];

# Computes the last day in the given month which occurs on the given 
# day of the week. Returns the day of the month [22, 31].
# 1 <= $month <= 12
# 0 <= $dow <= 6 (0=Sunday)
sub last_dow_in_month {
    my ($year, $month, $dow) = @_;

    $year  += int($month / 12);
    $month %= 12;

    my $time = Time::Local::timegm(0, 0, 0, 1, $month, $year) - 86400;
    my ($mday, $wday) = (gmtime($time))[3,6];
    return $mday - ($wday - $dow) % 7;
}

my $year = 2015;
foreach my $month (1..12) {
    printf "%.4d-%.2d-%.2d\n", 
      $year, $month, last_dow_in_month($year, $month, 5);
}
```

Output:

```
2015-01-30
2015-02-27
2015-03-27
2015-04-24
2015-05-29
2015-06-26
2015-07-31
2015-08-28
2015-09-25
2015-10-30
2015-11-27
2015-12-25
```

Using [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) the code becomes more readable:

```
use DateTime;

# Computes the last day in the given month which occurs on the given 
# day of the week. Returns the day of the month [22, 31].
# 1 <= $month <= 12
# 1 <= $dow <= 7 (1=Monday)
sub last_dow_in_month {
    my ($year, $month, $dow) = @_;

    my $dt = DateTime->last_day_of_month(year => $year, month => $month);
       $dt->subtract(days => ($dt->day_of_week - $dow) % 7);
    return $dt->day_of_month;
}
```

If performance is of essence, [Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment) can be used to compute it:

```
use Time::Moment qw[];

# Computes the last day in the given month which occurs on the given 
# day of the week. Returns the day of the month [22, 31].
# 1 <= $month <= 12
# 1 <= $dow <= 7 (1=Monday)
sub last_dow_in_month {
    my ($year, $month, $dow) = @_;

    my $tm = Time::Moment->new(year => $year, month => $month)
                         ->plus_months(1)
                         ->minus_days(1);
    return $tm->minus_days(($tm->day_of_week - $dow) % 7)
              ->day_of_month;
}
```

A correct implementation of your intended algorithm:

```
# Computes the last friday in the given month. Returns the day of the 
# month [22, 31].
# 1 <= $month <= 12
sub last_friday_in_month {
    my ($year, $month) = @_;

    my $days = (
        [0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365],
        [0, 31, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335, 366],
    )[($year % 4) == 0 && ($year % 100 != 0 || $year % 400 == 0)];

    my $y = $year - 1;
    my $k = 44 + $y + int($y/4) + int(6 * ($y/100)) + int($y/400);
    $k += $days->[$month];
    return $days->[$month] - $days->[$month - 1] - ($k % 7);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a few ways to do this.  Using [Time::Piece](http://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) isn't the simplest, it isn't designed for date math, but you don't have to install additional software.

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

sub get_last_dow_in_month {
    my($year, $month, $dow) = @_;

    # Get a Time::Piece object at the last day of the month.
    my $first_of_the_month = Time::Piece->strptime("$year $month", "%Y %m");
    my $last_day = $first_of_the_month->month_last_day;
    my $last_of_the_month  = Time::Piece->strptime("$year $month $last_day", "%Y %m %d");

    # Figure out how many days you need to go back.
    my $days_offset = -(($last_of_the_month->day_of_week + (7 - $dow)) % 7);

    return $last_of_the_month->mday + $days_offset;
}

say get_last_dow_in_month(2014, 3, 5);
```

If you need to do more date processing, [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) is the most comprehensive.

Comment: I downvoted this. Seriously, if you find yourself needing to interpolate scalars and invoking strptime() two times, you definitely know you are using the wrong module or algorithm!

Comment: @chansen As I said, Time::Piece is not the best module for date manipulation, using strptime is messy and its pretty bad that it does not include a basic constructor, but it is the best option that *comes with Perl as the OP requested*. Better than writing your own leap year and days-in-month functions. I work with what I'm given.  They should be fixing their "no CPAN modules" policy and using DateTime.

Answer (score 5):

Modules are made to be used. [Calc last friday of month on PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=740897) contains some examples.

E.g.

`$ perl -MDate::Manip -E 'say UnixDate(ParseDate("last Friday in March 2015"),"Last Friday of the month is %B %E, %Y.")`

`Last Friday of the month is March 27th, 2015.`

Rather than working around the technical limitation, you need to work around the social limitation that is hampering the technical side of your job.

Comment: [Link only answers are discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), could you add basics of what's in that link here?

Answer (score 0):

This is just for variety. As @Schwern notes, "`cal` is a clever hack, but it's a crutch that lets the OP avoid learning to use a good date library. Calendaring is hard, use a library."

Assuming you have `cal` on your system

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $ENV{LC_ALL} = 'C';

my @cal = `cal`;
my $last_friday;

for (my $i = $#cal; $i >= 0; $i -= 1) {
    my @dates = split ' ', $cal[$i];
    next unless @dates > 5;
    $last_friday = $dates[5];
    last;
}

print "$last_friday\n";
```

Or, more succinctly, but somewhat less efficiently:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $ENV{LC_ALL} = 'C';

my ($last_friday) = grep defined, map +(split)[5], reverse `cal`;

print "$last_friday\n";
```

Or, even,

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw( first );

local $ENV{LC_ALL} = 'C';

my $last_friday = first { defined } map +(split)[5], reverse `cal`;

print "$last_friday\n";
```

Comment: It's a shame this is the accepted answer.  Using cal is a clever hack, but it's a crutch that lets the OP avoid learning to use a good date library.  Calendaring is hard, use a library.

Comment: @Schwern I agree. That's why I prefaced the answer with "for variety" because you had adequately answered the question. That's also why I improved daotoad's answer by adding another library example.

Comment: This code shouldn't be used! Shelling to a command should always be the last resort!

Comment: @chansen It depends. ["On Forking" by MJD](http://perl.plover.com/yak/12views/samples/notes.html): "*Let's not forget the things that are good about Perl. It's good at interacting with other programs, and it's good for rapid prototyping. Let's not hassle people when they use Perl the way it was designed to be used.*"

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I accepted it was quick fix available at the time. But now I used epoch time for date and time and used it to find the day.

Comment: @SinanÜnür, I generally agree with that, but when there is a portable way to achieve the same thing I tend to prefer that.